# Quicksight calucalted field /YTD calculations

Tags: calculated-field, amazon-quicksight, qliksense

Sum($(vSetYTD) ResidentDays) this calculated field is doing sum of "residentDays' while setting YTD function(This expression is used in qlik sense/qlikview.)
Now in quicksight how to set a similar YTD function so that if I have given a filter/control of date(Year).My YTD changes automatically to that year.
Example 2021 YTD of sum(residentdays)=80%
after selecting the year as 2020 I get YTD of 2020 year.
Looking for positive response

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to calculate YTD and MTD in quicksight how to do that

Answer (score 0):

For Period to date calculations in quicksight: periodToDateSum()

YTD: periodToDateSum(Sales, Order_date, YEAR)

MTD: periodToDateSum(Sales, Order_date, MONTH)